# What does the appending zero mean in a C assignment statement?

Tags: c

I am writing to inquire a quick question regarding a wired C statement. The following statement is found in libgcrypt 1.7.3, line 680 of mpi/mpi-pow.c.

```
base_u_size |= (precomp_size[k] & ((mpi_size_t)0 - (k == e0)) );
```

So the appending `0` after `mpi_size_t` seems so wired to me. I also show the following assembly code sequence, which corresponds to this source code statement:

```
              mov    -0x138(%ebp),%eax
              mov    -0x48(%ebp,%eax,4),%edx
              mov    -0x138(%ebp),%eax
              cmp    -0x114(%ebp),%eax  <----- eax = k, -0x114(%ebp) = e0
              jne    80b84b2 <_gcry_mpi_powm+0xeee>
              mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
              jmp   80b84b7 <_gcry_mpi_powm+0xef3>
     80b84b2: mov    $0x0,%eax
     80b84b7: and    %edx,%eax
```

So somehow the `0` does not lead to any effect here?

Comment: You just cast `0` to `mpi_size_t`.

Comment: Interestingly, and assuming `mpi_size_t` is an unsigned type, the zero isn't needed. `- (k == e0)` can be interpreted as (arithmetic) negation of the condition, giving an `int` 0 or -1. The cast can then be applied to *that* in order to obtain the exact same result.

Comment: @StoryTeller:  I encountered one strange compiler not long ago, that gave me a warning like, `Warning: applying integer negation to boolean expression`, which may be the reason to use subtraction, rather than negation.

Comment: @abelenky - Honestly, that sounds like a warning I'd just turn off. I'm kinda more inclined to believe whomever wrote this code was going for less of a WTF factor. Or so one can hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *So the appending 0 after `mpi_size_t`*

It's called [type-casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

By definition, integer constant values, are of type `int`. To make is explicitly of type `mpi_size_t`, you cast the value to the required type.

Comment: @lllllllllllll That'd be a syntax error. Moreover `<...>size_t` nomenclature is usually for types, not variables.

Answer (score 1):

The `0` after `mpi_size_t` is for typecasting it (0) to the type `mpi_size_t`

Answer (score 1):

> What does the appending zero mean in a C assignment statement?

```
base_u_size |= (precomp_size[k] & ((mpi_size_t)0 - (k == e0)) );
```

As well answer by [@Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54291651/2410359), it casts the 0 to type `mpi_size_t`.

---

To answer *why* code performs the cast?

In `mpi/mpi-pow.c`, `base_u_size` is of type `mpi_size_t`.
To insure the right side of the assignment is done using *at least* the rank and width of `mpi_size_t` math and quiet warnings of mixed signed types.

By including a `mpi_size_t` on the right side, the subtraction and the `&` use a width that does not lose information.

With the types of the objects involved as [here](https://github.com/gpg/libgcrypt/blob/master/mpi/mpi-pow.c) ( I do not have exactly what OP is using), it is likely to make no difference here.  `base_u_size |= precomp_size[k] & -(k == e0);` would have been fine - yet bring up persnickety warnings.

OP's code is a common idiom (do right hand math at least as wide as left size and strive for same signnesss) to prevent problems.